# Hadoop Reducer Iterate Twice in JAVA

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have following input in rvalue

```
14
7
39
40
```

Expected output

```
14  
14
7
39
40

7
14
7
39
40
.
.
.
```

In first for loop it will read the value 14 and in nested for-loop it read the value 14 next 14,7  & 14,39 etc..

On mine below code, it's not working, when I print "`cache.size();`" it print the value `1` also when I print the variable `i` it also prints as `1`. Please let me know what's wrong on this?

```
public static class Reducerclass  extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text> {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a");

    public void reduce(Text rkey, Iterable<Text> rvalue, Context context) 
                                       throws IOException, InterruptedException {            
        ArrayList<String> cache = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(Text value : rvalue) {  
            cache.add(value.toString());
        }   

        int size = cache.size();    
        System.out.println("size-->" + cache.size());

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { 
            System.out.println("  i -->" + i);
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                System.out.println("  j -->" + j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like there is only one element in `rvalue` it is most likely a "14,7,39,40". Print out `value.toString()` and see what it is.

Comment: @tsolakp: sorry I have edited my input data as 14 7 39 40 (line by line)

Answer (score 0):

what is the output of:

```
  for(Text value : rvalue) {  
            System.out.println(value.toString()+","+cache.size())
            cache.add(value.toString());
        }
```

lets say its something like

```
14,1
7,1
39,1 ...
```

then you actually dont have those values in rvalue, instead your seeing the output of multiple reducers running on that dataset, you can verify by

```
System.out.println(key.toString()+","+value.toString()+","+cache.size())
```

however if it is something like

```
14,1
7,2
39,3 ...
```

then the problem is that you are only printing i and j

```
    System.out.println("  i -->" + i);
    System.out.println("  i -->" + i);
```

instead of the values in the cache:

```
System.out.println(cache.get(i)+","+cache.get(j))
```

Comment: 14 7 39 40 (line by line)

Comment: weird! can you print size too?

Comment: size is "1". This is the problem faced, printing "value.toString()" inside the for loop and printing outside the for loop "cache.size()" . it prints like below
4 1 7 1 39 1 40 1 (input value  , size  repeating like this.)

Comment: you actually dont have those values in rvalue, instead your seeing the output of multiple reducers running on that dataset, you can verify by

System.out.println(key.toString()+","+value.toString()+","+cache.size())

incorporated this into my answer

Comment: for this Print System.out.println(key.toString()+","+value.toString()+","+cache.size()). The output looks like  14,1
7,1
39,1

Comment: i dont see the key or the leading "," in the output did you perhaps mean 
 ,14,1/n,7,7/n ?